# Deezer Player Widget not working in safari

Tags: deezer

somebody knows if the Deezer Player Widget widget have problems to run in Safari. I have try it in different computers, and the plugin don't do anything.

Comment: There are some problems on Safari because of 3rd party cookie policy, so you have to login to Deezer before using the widget in order to use it correctly. We are working on it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it seems that it results from a deliberate policy. It is now impossible to embed any deezer player in any web page. But it is not written on the site which continues to offer widgets that do not work. The only thing to regret is that there is no other competitor at the moment. It would be more honorable if the real policy of deezer was truly said. A lie even by omission is never a good thing. It always leaves a bad taste in the palate.